# Angular 2.0.1 : router and canActivate class not working : No Directive annotation found on LoginGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

here is my problem with latest Angular 2 (2.0.1) and angular router : 3.0.1

When I run application I have the following error :
***Error: (SystemJS) No Directive annotation found on LoginGuard(…)***

I have a router with a canActivate class to control access to route, here is the code :

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule  } from '@angular/router';
export const MainWindowRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/web-portal',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'web-portal',
    component: MainWindowComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'device/:id', component: DeviceViewComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'location/:id', component: LocationViewComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'deviceType/:id', component: DeviceTypeViewComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: WelcomeViewComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '', component: RouterComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  }
];
export const LoginRoutes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
export const AUTH_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [LoginGuard, LoginService];
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...LoginRoutes,
    ...MainWindowRoutes
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here is the loginGuard class :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { 
    CanActivate,
    Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { routing } from '../app.routes';

@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {


constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        console.log('canActivate !!!');

      if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) { 
            return true; 
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In app.module I boostrap the router like this :

```
bootstrap:  (AppComponent, [AUTH_ROUTER_PROVIDERS ])
```

But it's not working at all. Injection seems not working correctly for canActivate class (LoginGuard).

Please help! ;-)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap line in is invalid. It should be something like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ModuleWithProviders],
  providers: [AUTH_ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  ...
}
export class AppModule {}
```

```
// The browser platform with a compiler
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// The app module
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Compile and launch the module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#bootstrap

Comment: Your `bootstrap` line looks quite different.

Comment: Add `ModuleWithProviders` to `imports` as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: and add `AUTH_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to `providers` in `NgModule`

Comment: Did you make all changes I suggested? Then please edit your question and demonstrate what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok good it works now.

In fact I forgot to add that into app.module :

providers : [   AUTH_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    appRoutingProviders,...

Damned, I could not guess that. Sometimes refactoring renders the code more complex. Not sure it is a good idea to have all providers into app.module...
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of @Gunter answer don't forget to include in import in NgModule and **"routing"** property of your code.